# Perl modules for connecting H2db

Tags: database, perl, database-connection, h2, h2db

I have an perl code where we are reading .txt files but now inspite of .txt we want to read data from H2DB database. I tried to searching out and seems that no modules are available for that . Can some one of you please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

H2 supports Postgresql network protocol, so you can try to do this
using postgres's driver

here are the modules you can use:

```
use DBI;

$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname", "", "");

# for some advanced uses you may need PostgreSQL type values:
use DBD::Pg qw(:pg_types);

 # See the DBI module documentation for full details
```